# Convert C Callback byte array into uint16_t array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am using a video camera that outputs 12 bit imagery data. The callback that is used to receive a frame returns an 8 bit array where the 12 bit data is split across two bytes in the format below.

```
|              Byte 1           |              Byte 2           |
| 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
|MSB| X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X |LSB| - | - | - | - |
```

This means that for a x*y sized image the data length will be x*y*2 as twice the number of elements will be present. Below is the callback function in python, this is the data entry point for the camera.

```
@ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_byte), ctypes.c_ulong)
    def receive_frame(_context, data, data_length):
```

`data` is a pointer to the memory with the imagery.

`data_length` is the size of the pointer.

I would ideally like the data in a numpy array using dtype np.uint_16 but ingesting the array into numpy is causing my program to be two slow as it takes around ~0.8s-0.9s per frame to process this information and I wish to capture at 30fps meaning I ideally need it to be around 0.03s (I have multiprocessing in place to distribute the processing, see the bottom)

```
nlist = np.asarray(data[:data_length], dtype='<B')
nlist = np.right_shift(nlist.view(np.uint16), 4).reshape(2464, 2048)
```

As far as I can tell this is giving me exactly what I want (see below) but it is too slow.

```
|                              Element 1                              |
| 15 | 14 | 13 | 12 | 11 | 10 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| -  | -  | -  | -  |MSB | X  | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X |LSB|
```

I beleive that there is a much faster way of doing this as getting the data into numpy in the first instance is taking a long time. I have included some timings below.

```
nlist = np.asarray(data[:data_length], dtype='<B')
Takes: ~0.8515s

nlist = np.right_shift(nlist.view(np.uint16), 4).reshape(464, 664)
Takes: ~0.0070s
```

More Notes:
As I said, i am using multiprocessing to attempt to decouple receiving the data and processing it. This means in reality my callback function looks like the function below. I wish I didn't have to use global variables but as far as I can tell you cannot access self in a callback function (please prove me wrong!)

```
@ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_byte), ctypes.c_ulong)
def receive_frame(_context, data, data_length):
    global GLOBAL_FRAME_QUEUE, GLOBAL_FRAME_COUNT
    GLOBAL_FRAME_QUEUE.put([GLOBAL_FRAME_COUNT, data[:data_length]])
    GLOBAL_FRAME_COUNT += 1
```

The above function adds the frame number and the frame to a multiprocessing.Queue() where the following multiprocessed pool picks it up.

```
@staticmethod
def frame_processing_pool_function(centers, points_masks_dict, frame_queue, output_queue):
    while True:
        queue_item = frame_queue.get()
        list = queue_item[1]
        nlist = np.asarray(list, dtype='<B')
        nlist = np.right_shift(nlist.view(np.uint16), 4).reshape(464, 664)
        ...
```

`frame_queue` in this case is GLOBAL_FRAME_QUEUE.

I think there may be a solution in OpenCV but I am yet to find it.

Thanks in advance for your help.